# Once an event is bound in jQuery how do you get a reference to the event handler function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I attach a click event handler:

```
$(".selector").bind("click", function () {
  // some handler function
});
```

How can I get a reference to that function? This doesn't work:

```
var refToFunc = $(".selector").bind("click");
typeof refToFunc === "object";  // I want the function
```

I think `bind("eventname")` in that case just returns the jQuery object and not the event handler function. It must be stored somewhere.

Comment: Do you want to avoid introducing variables by either defining the function outside of the bind call or binding it to a variable inside the call?

Comment: Yeah, I just want to store it and temporarily unbind the events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very interesting question. You can retrieve it like this:

```
var refToFunc = $(".selector").data("events")["click"][0].handler;
```

Note that we used `[0]` because you have an array of handlers, in case you bound more than one handler.  For other events, just change to the event name.

**EDIT**
In general, you could use the following plugin to get all handlers of the selected elements for an event (code not optimized yet):

```
$.fn.getEventHandlers = function(eventName){
  var handlers = [];
  this.each(function(){
     $.each($(this).data("events")[eventName], function(i, elem){
         handlers.push(elem.handler);    
     });     
  });
  return handlers;
};
```

How to use it?:

```
$(".selector").getEventHandlers("click");
```

And it would return an array of functions containing all event handlers.

For your specific question, you could use this plugin like this:

```
var refToFunc = $(".selector").getEventHandlers("click")[0];
```

Hope this helps. cheers

Comment: that [0] scares me ... your handler might not be in the 0th position by the time you are ready to unbind it

Answer (score 5):

Event handlers are kept in a data object, accessible through `data`.  For instance:

```
$('.selector').data('events').click[0].handler;
```

This gets the first event handler function bound to the `click` event of this function.

---

If you want to keep a reference for the function e.g. for unbinding it, it would be better to store it in a variable or make it a named function.

```
var handler = function() {
    // some content
});

$('.selector').bind('click', handler);
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll want to store it to temporarily unbind and re-bind later. The named option is nice, but I won't always have control over the functions that get added.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the functions I ended up with:

```
var getEventHandlers = function ($object, eventName) {
    var handlers = [],
        eventHandlers = $object.data("events")[eventName];
    if (eventHandlers && eventHandlers.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, l = eventHandlers.length; i < l; i++) {
            handlers.push(eventHandlers[i].handler);
        }
    }
    return handlers;
},
setEventHandlers = function ($object, eventName, handlers) {
    if (handlers && handlers.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, l = handlers.length; i < l; i++) {
            $object.bind(eventName, handlers[i]);
        }
    }
};
```