# jQuery add element to previously defined event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery, is it possible to add elements to a previously defined event handler? I realize the right way to do this would be to define the handler using `on()` so that dynamically inserted elements will be included, but the issue is the handler I'm trying to extend is defined by code on a server that I don't have access to.  The server outputs code like this at the top of the file:

```
$('#wrapper .block h2').click(function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Then, towards the bottom of the page, I've added some custom javascript code that inserts another `#wrapper .block h2` element. I'm wondering if there is any way for me to include this new element in the event handler that was defined by the code at the top of the page where the `click` handler was registered.

Or, is there any way for me to programmatically access the callback function that was defined for that event handler? That way I could recreate it myself using the `on()` method.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6631570/218196 and see if it still works.

Comment: Unbelievable thank you so much @FelixKling that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @flyingL123 Does it still works? In my experience `data('events')` doesn't work anymore. There is another way though to achieve it.

Comment: Oh really @dfsq ? Yes it worked for me from a quick test in console, but is it not 100% reliable? What is the other way to achieve it that you mentioned?

Comment: It worked for you probably because you tried it with version <1.8. In newer versions `data('events')` won't work. I will post another way around which works with current versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you need to access internal event handles stored by jQuery. In previous versions ([prior to 1.8](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10589)) you could do it using Data API, like `$('.some').data('events')`. However it's no longer available. However you can still access element data object with `$._data` method. Then you would do something like this:

```
var events = $._data($(selector)[0], 'events'),
    click = events && events.click;

if (click) $el.on('click', click[0].handler);
```

**However** be aware that `$._data` is a private property, and there is no guarantee that it will not change one day (like previously you could access element data with `$.cache`, but it's gone now).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/e94hau62/

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible for you just to write a new event handler on the same action, it should replace the old one and leave the action to your new one.

Try it out in the console or commandline.

Comment: Im suggesting that a possible overwrite of the current event listener should be possible.

Comment: But overwrite with what? The existing event handler should still work as expected as far as I can tell.

Comment: If he is not trying to replace it then he can just add it. I don't understand where the complications is then.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is, you define the handle in server side, it will be like,

```
var yourhandler = function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Then after you load your new elements, you can hood the "yourhandler" to them, like,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#wrapper .block h2').click(yourhandler);
});
```